'inverting' an LFO output
I want to 'invert' the output of an LFO I built. This is for use in a CV Synthesizer environment where all signals are 0V to 5V. By inverting I mean if for example I have a ramp going from 0V to 5V, I want an output signal to go convertedly from 5V to 0V. I suppose I can achieve this with an opamp, but I couldn't find the proper design without getting an offset in the output. I can use a TL072, LM358 or LM324, with +-12V, or whatever it takes.

It can be done with a differential amplifier which does the operation (5V - V_LFO) because since your LFO is 0V-5V this operation would invert the sawtooth, below an example of the topology proposed:

It produces the following output:

Hope this helps, note that the resistors should be selected based on the output impedance of your LFO, and keep in mind that this would work for any waveform, not only sawtooth.
As an extra, I'll attach an image of the differential amplifier configuration of the opamp so you can see where this came from:

Edit:
Opamps must be powered from such voltages that the dynamic range of the opamp satisfies the output voltage range. If you are implementing an Eurorack system using the +12V and -12V rails would be the most appropriate.
Edit 2: (follow up on some questions)
You need to pay close attention to the output impedance of the LFO, in the circuit below it is represented by the 10k in series I added to the LFO Voltage source. Note the output of this circuit when an impedance coupling error happens.


One of the solutions could be to increase all of the differential amplifier resistances. Like this:


the downside: the output is still not the same amplitude as the input, but the error is much smaller compared to when there was an impedance coupling error. I guess this the output would be as in a voltage divider created by the output impedance of the LFO and the input impedance of the differential amplifier) in this case, something like (10K/(100K+10K)) = 0.909, so expect to see 0.909 as the original amplitude.
Solution 2:
The second solution is to buffer the LFO output, this can be done with another opamp in a voltage follower configuration, below the schematic and response (Note that I replaced the differential amplifier resistances to a much lower value to make a point that there is no mismatch due to the opamp, in practice use a higher value, such as 50K or 100k to reduce power consumption and heat dissipation):


With this you should be able to fit this circuit to your needs, good luck!

Thank you, I will try this, but how do you power the opamp, and which model is it?

Since you are going for Eurorack you can go dual supply, I suppose you could use a cheap LM324 (Quad Op Amp) or something like an OP07 (Single Opamp) supplied with +12 and -12, this will give the opamps a dynamic range of something like ±10V, this only because this is an LFO, I think if the bandwidth of these devices is Ok for an LFO, LM324 has a bandwidth of about 1.17 MHz according to LTspice

I tried your topo with a LM324, +-12v with all 10Ks, and I'm still getting a weakened wave oscillating around +2.5V..I really don't know what I'm doing wrong..

I changed for 100Ks, and getting 2.5V PP around +2.5V..I don't get it..

I edited the question I'm certain it has to do with an impedance coupling problem.

Apparently it does..this is a fun little LFO from Electric Druid https://electricdruid.net/product/stomplfo/ .. Maybe I should start by buffering it first?

Anyway I tried your design with a Signal Generator, and it works perfectly of course, so I will gladly give you the answer.. Nonetheless if you have any idea on how to deal with this with that particular LFO, I'd be happy to hear. Thank you

Thank you for the edits, I commented before I saw them.

I guess a proper signal processing path is key, maybe adding a more complex opamp configuration that enables DC offsetting and Scaling and also adding an output power amplifier, something like a push-pull amplifier to make the output signal withstand higher current sinking/sourcing and some output resistances to limit this same current to prevent damage to your module and other modules, Good luck!

Thank you very much Cheche, I buffered my LFO first and I'm getting almost perfect result. I struggled 3 hours with ChatBlaBla, then got the answer from a way smarter person on this great website in 30 minutes! Thank you again.

To convert some input signal \$V_{IN}\$ going from 0V to +5V into a signal \$V_{OUT}\$ going from +5V to 0V, then the relationship between them is:
$$ V_{OUT} = \overbrace{(-1)}^{Gain}\times V_{IN} + \overbrace{(+5V)}^{Offset}$$
You need a system with gain −1, and which adds +5V. Here's a complete design that will do exactly that, and which directly answers your question:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This design does not require precise power supplies, and will work with any dual supply beyond ±7V. The output will not be significantly affected by supply noise or voltage variation. Pretty much any op-amp will work here, provided it can tolerate the total supply potential difference of 18V.
The output \$V_{OUT}\$ is in blue in the plot below, corresponding to an input \$V_{IN}\$ swept between 0V and +5V:

That's the TLDR, and you can stop right here if you want, but what follows is an explanation of how it works, and my reasoning.
At the bottom of this answer I have added a second slightly simpler design which performs the same function.

Obtaining a gain of −1 is easy:

simulate this circuit
That's a classic inverting amplifier, with gain \$-\frac{R_3}{R_1}=-1\$. Now we need to add 5V. The above design can be modified to become a summing amplifier, by introducing a second input path, as follows:

simulate this circuit
The relationship between \$V_{IN1}\$, \$V_{IN2}\$ and \$V_{OUT}\$ is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= -V_{IN1}\frac{R_3}{R_1} - V_{IN2}\frac{R_3}{R_2} \\ \\
&= -R_3 \left( \frac{V_{IN1}}{R_1} + \frac{V_{IN2}}{R_2}\right) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Hopefully from that it's clear that the design adds \$V_{IN1}\$ and \$V_{IN2}\$, each scaled by the value of their associated resistance, and then inverts.
You'll notice I haven't specified R2, and that's because I don't know \$V_{IN2}\$ yet. To add +5V to the signal, we'll need \$V_{IN2}\$ to be negative:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= -V_{IN1}\frac{R_3}{R_1} - V_{IN2}\frac{R_3}{R_2} \\ \\
&= -V_{IN1}\frac{R_3}{R_1} - (-5V) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
We must find values of \$V_{IN2}\$ and \$R_2\$ that satisfy:
$$ V_{IN2}\frac{R_3}{R_2} = -5V $$
\$R_3\$ is already known to be 10kΩ, so we just need to find some combination of \$V_{IN2}\$ and \$R_2\$. In my design I don't use the power supply to obtain \$V_{IN2}\$, for two reasons:

The negative supply of −9V can change over time, as batteries discharge, or voltage regulators heat up or age.

The supplies can be noisy, contain small fluctuations that we don't want appearing in the output.


I chose to use the cheap, readily available, and very popular TL431 IC, which is a precision voltage reference. In the configuration above it produces a very precise 2.5V potential difference, so I use it to obtain a potential 2.5V below ground (0V):
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{IN2} &= -2.5V \\ \\
V_{IN2}\frac{R_3}{R_2} &= -5V \\ \\
R_2 &= \frac{V_{IN2}R_3}{-5V} \\ \\
&= \frac{-2.5V \times 10k\Omega}{-5V} \\ \\
&= 5k\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

An alternative design, using one fewer resistors, but producing the exact same result:

simulate this circuit
I won't go into the details of how this works, but this other answer I wrote may help to clarify.

thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. As you could see I got my problem solved already but thank you again.

@brunobhr only solved if your 5V source is exactly 5V, and with no ripple. And the op-amp still requires supplies greater than 5V and less than 0V, in addition to the 5V reference source.

the opamp is powered with +-12V, and the 5V source comes from a very accurate 7805.

@brunobhr Fair enough!
